# How I can make my app geometry to change dynamically?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to my app geometry to adapt to my screen geometry (for example: if my screen resolution is 1280x720 my app geometry automatically change to 1280x720 from 1920x1080). I know is fullscreen, but when I change the screen resolution from code, the line will not appear where is the cursor. So, please help me!

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QMenu, QMenuBar, QAction, QFileDialog, QDesktopWidget, QLabel, QGridLayout, QActionGroup
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QImage, QPainter, QPen, QBrush
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import sys

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        title="Draw!"
        top= 400
        left= 400
        width= 1920
        height= 1080

        icon="icons/paint.png"

        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.setGeometry(top, left, width, height)
        self.showFullScreen()
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(icon))

        self.image= QImage(self.size(), QImage.Format_RGB32)
        self.image.fill(Qt.white)

        self.drawing= False
        self.brushSize= 2
        self.brushColor= Qt.black
        self.lastPoint= QPoint()

        mainMenu=self.menuBar()
        fileMenu=mainMenu.addMenu("File")
        brushSize=mainMenu.addMenu("Brush Size")
        brushColor=mainMenu.addMenu("Brush Color")

        quitAction= QtWidgets.QAction("Quit", self.window())
        quitAction.setShortcut("Esc")
        fileMenu.addAction(quitAction)
        quitAction.triggered.connect(self.exit)

        saveAction=QAction(QIcon("icons/save.png"), "Save",self)
        saveAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+S")
        fileMenu.addAction(saveAction)
        saveAction.triggered.connect(self.save)

        clearAction=QAction(QIcon("icons/clear.png"), "Clear",self)
        clearAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+C")
        fileMenu.addAction(clearAction)
        clearAction.triggered.connect(self.clear)

        eraseAction=QAction(QIcon("icons/erase.png"), "Erase",self)
        eraseAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+E")
        fileMenu.addAction(eraseAction)
        eraseAction.triggered.connect(self.erase)

        threepxAction=QAction(QIcon("icons/threepx.png"), "3px", self)
        brushSize.addAction(threepxAction)
        threepxAction.triggered.connect(self.threePixel)

        fivepxAction=QAction(QIcon("icons/fivepx.png"), "5px", self)
        brushSize.addAction(fivepxAction)
        fivepxAction.triggered.connect(self.fivePixel)

        sevenpxAction=QAction(QIcon("icons/sevenpx.png"), "7px", self)
        brushSize.addAction(sevenpxAction)
        sevenpxAction.triggered.connect(self.sevenPixel)

        ninepxAction=QAction(QIcon("icons/ninepx.png"), "9px", self)
        brushSize.addAction(ninepxAction)
        ninepxAction.triggered.connect(self.ninePixel)

        elevenpxAction=QAction(QIcon("icons/elevenpx.png"), "11px", self)
        brushSize.addAction(elevenpxAction)
        elevenpxAction.triggered.connect(self.elevenPixel)

        twentypxAction=QAction(QIcon("icons/twentypx.png"), "20px", self)
        brushSize.addAction(twentypxAction)
        twentypxAction.triggered.connect(self.twentyPixel)

        bucketpxAction=QAction(QIcon("icons/bucketpx.png"), "Bucket", self)
        brushSize.addAction(bucketpxAction)
        bucketpxAction.triggered.connect(self.bucketPixel)

        blackAction=QAction(QIcon("icons/black.png"), "Black", self)
        blackAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+B")
        brushColor.addAction(blackAction)
        blackAction.triggered.connect(self.blackColor)

        whiteAction=QAction(QIcon("icons/white.png"), "White", self)
        whiteAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+W")
        brushColor.addAction(whiteAction)
        whiteAction.triggered.connect(self.whiteColor)

        redAction=QAction(QIcon("icons/red.png"), "Red", self)
        redAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+R")
        brushColor.addAction(redAction)
        redAction.triggered.connect(self.redColor)

        greenAction=QAction(QIcon("icons/green.png"), "Green", self)
        greenAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+G")
        brushColor.addAction(greenAction)
        greenAction.triggered.connect(self.greenColor)

        yellowAction=QAction(QIcon("icons/yellow.png"), "Yellow", self)
        yellowAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+Y")
        brushColor.addAction(yellowAction)
        yellowAction.triggered.connect(self.yellowColor)

        blueAction=QAction(QIcon("icons/blue.png"), "Blue", self)
        blueAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+B")
        brushColor.addAction(blueAction)
        blueAction.triggered.connect(self.blueColor)



    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.drawing= True
            self.lastPoint= event.pos()
            #print(self.lastPoint)


    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if(event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton) & self.drawing:
            painter=QPainter(self.image)
            painter.setPen(QPen(self.brushColor, self.brushSize, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
            painter.drawLine(self.lastPoint, event.pos())
            self.lastPoint= event.pos()
            self.update()


    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() ==Qt.LeftButton:
            self.drawing= False

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        canvasPainter=QPainter(self)
        canvasPainter.drawImage(self.rect(), self.image, self.image.rect())
    

    def save(self):
        filePath, _=QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save Image", "", "PNG(*.png);;JPEG(*.jpg *.jpeg);;All Files(*.*)")
        if filePath=="":
            return
        self.image.save(filePath)

    def exit(self):
        QtWidgets.qApp.quit()

    def clear(self):
        self.image.fill(Qt.white)
        self.update()

    def erase(self):
        self.brushSize= 5
        self.brushColor=Qt.white



    def threePixel(self):
        self.brushSize= 3
    def fivePixel(self):
        self.brushSize= 5
    def sevenPixel(self):
        self.brushSize= 7
    def ninePixel(self):
        self.brushSize= 9
    def elevenPixel(self):
        self.brushSize = 11
    def twentyPixel(self):
        self.brushSize = 20


    def blackColor(self):
        self.brushColor=Qt.black
    def whiteColor(self):
        self.brushColor=Qt.white
    def redColor(self):
        self.brushColor=Qt.red
    def greenColor(self):
        self.brushColor=Qt.green
    def yellowColor(self):
        self.brushColor=Qt.yellow
    def blueColor(self):
        self.brushColor=Qt.blue
    def bucketPixel(self):
        self.image.fill(self.brushColor)



if __name__=="__main__":
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    window= Window()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting your question. The title of the question refers to the geometry, but then you complain about the lines drawn. *What* is the problem?

Comment: I want to my app geometry to change dynamically

Comment: Change according to what? Also, you wrote "when I change the screen resolution from code", what does that mean? Qt doesn't allow to change the screen resolution. Please be more specific, as your whole question is *very* unclear. Besides that, it includes *a lot* of unnecessary code, please always try to provide [minimal, reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (emphasis on *minimal*).

Comment: I want to my app geometry to change dynamically according to screen resolution

Comment: I still don't understand: you are *already* using `showFullScreen()` which automatically updates the window geometry to the screen even when the screen resolution changes.

Comment: I resolved that, thanks a lot!